# Can't get grand child value in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get the grand child value from local json file. It will work perfectly all other pages. But I couldn't get the value while using useEffect. I can get child object value. But I'm not able to get the grand child value.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProductDetails = (props) => {
    const [Product, SetProduct] = useState({});
    const { ProductId } = useParams();
    const GetProduct = props.ProductData.products;
    useEffect(() => {
        const GetItem = (item) => {
            item.forEach(element => {
                if (element.id === ProductId) {
                    SetProduct(element)
                }
            });
        }
        GetItem(GetProduct)
    }, [GetProduct, ProductId])
    console.log(Product.img.thumbnail)
```

This is my JSON structure

```
"products": [
    {
        "id": "",
        "code": "",
        "name": "",
        "img": {
            "homeSlider": "",
            "thumbnail": "",
            "cover": [
                {
                    "front": "",
                    "back": "",
                    "side": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "",
        "code": "",
        "name": "",
        "img": {
            "homeSlider": "",
            "thumbnail": "",
            "cover": [
                {
                    "front": "",
                    "back": "",
                    "side": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

[image]

Please help me for this situation.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The initial state is an empty object:

```
const [Product, SetProduct] = useState({});
```

An empty object has no `img` property, so this will throw the exact error you're seeing:

```
console.log(Product.img.thumbnail)
```

Either add a property to the initial object:

```
const [Product, SetProduct] = useState({ img: {} });
```

Or don't try to use that property unless it exists:

```
if (Product.img) {
  console.log(Product.img.thumbnail)
}
```

Comment: But I can get the "id', "code", "name" values.

Comment: @DhivaharM: And in the very first render of the component, what are those values?  All three of them are `undefined`, because your object is an empty object with no properties.  You can "get" them, but they don't do anything meaningful.  However, if you try to *dereference* an `undefined` value (try to get a property on an `undefined` value) then that will produce the exact error you're seeing.

Comment: It is working now. But I have doubt. I have multiple children and sub children properties. Should I do the same for all children?

const [Product, SetProduct] = useState({ img: {}, url:{}, display:{} }); Like this?

Comment: Sorry I know I'm bothering you. But Im newbie for ReactJs. so that

Comment: @DhivaharM: This doesn't really have anything to do with React, the same is true for any JavaScript objects (or objects in pretty much any language).  Consider the analogy you're using of "child" and "grandchild".  When you have an object with no "child" properties, how can you expect to reference a "grandchild" property?  You just need to either (1) create default properties or (2) check that properties exist before trying to use them.  At its simplest, you can't read properties from `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: Make sense. Let me try. Thank you so much @David

Comment: @DhivaharM Generally you will want to apply the null-check/guard-clause pattern when accessing potentially undefined object properties, i.e. `console.log(Product && Product.img && Product.img.thumbnail)` or more succinctly using Optional Chaining operator `console.log(Product?.img?.thumbnail)`.

Answer (score 0):

this is not about capturing the grand child. you get this error because your condition does not meet and though you have an empty object.so you don't have and "img" property on an empty object.